# How to append real time calculations from streaming twitter API to dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, python-3.5, twitter-streaming-api

I am need to some analysis on text from tweets coming from the streaming API, and my question is **in real time how do I append my numerical results calculations along with a few dictionary keys and their data to the same dataframe from the streaming twitter API?**

**The error I get is "TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object"**

Code so far:

```
# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""


score = pd.DataFrame()


# This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):


    def on_data(self, data):
        dataset = pd.DataFrame()
        tweetObj = json.loads(data)
        keys =  tweetObj.keys()
        #print (keys)
        if 'text' in tweetObj:
            score.append((tweetObj['text']))
        else:
            ('This does not have a text entry')   
        texts = (tweetObj['text'])
        wiki = TextBlob(texts)
        self.r = wiki.sentiment.polarity
        score.append(self.r)
        #print(len(score))
        return(self.r)





auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())

# Searches by the keywords
stream.filter(track=['oil','gold','iron ore','uranium'],languages=['en'], stall_warnings=True)


# DF

print(score.head())
```

The variable `"self.r"` is the calculations I want to append in the dataframe `"scores"`

The keys object is where the dictionary keys are stored in this format, I have tried to append them in the if statement but no luck.  :

```
dict_keys(['contributors', 'favorited', 'timestamp_ms', 'id', 'extended_entities', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'user', 'source', 'favorite_count', 'truncated', 'place', 'coordinates', 'id_str', 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'filter_level', 'in_reply_to_status_id', 'retweet_count', 'retweeted', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'retweeted_status', 'text', 'entities', 'created_at', 'geo', 'is_quote_status', 'lang', 'possibly_sensitive'])
```

my goal is to create a dataframe that looks like the below with the column names based on the dictionary keys themselves like so:

```
    score    text        contributors
0   .3       'aaa'       '@b'
1   .3       'aaa'       '@b'
2   .3       'aaa'       '@b'
```

As a bonus I would like to also be able to stop the stream after certain number of tweets, but not sure how to do this.

I have tried this with the line:

```
keys =  tweetObj.keys(500)
```

but get error:

```
TypeError: keys() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Hope this makes sense, Thank you in advance!